# psycopg cannot be imported in VSCode (import error)

Tags: visual-studio-code, psycopg2

I know the same question already exists here, but regarding Windows and no vitual-env.

I run ubuntu 20.04 with python3-venv and python 3.8.
In python3 command line I can import psycopg2 and connect to a database.
Only VS code gives me an import error on psycopg2.

```
python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
>>>
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the reason.

I did a

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
git add *; git commit -m "savepoint"; git push
```

and commited all to my git repository. After that I deleted the whole project directory.

Then I created a new venv project and cloned the previously saved git repository.

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

did install all necessary python modules including psycopg2.
After that VS code could import psycopg2.

I think this was an issue with wrong dependenties in venv cache.